# Swift 4 NSLocale How to get currency code via country code?

Tags: ios, swift, currency, swift4, nslocale

I want to display country list and when user select one of them country i need it's currency code in order to convert currency. The problem is that i can't get currency code via country code.The following code is displaying the list of countries.

```
var countries: [String] = []
for code in NSLocale.isoCountryCodes as [String] {
        let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code])
        let name = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_UK").displayName(forKey: .identifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
        countries.append(name)
}
print(countries)
```

Comment: "i can't get currency code" You're not _trying_ to get a currency code. I don't see anything about currency in your code. (And use Locale, please, not NSLocale.)

Comment: @nAkhmedov https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172167/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks i managed via rmaddy 's answer